# Change YouTube username to Google username on non-Gmail accounts

Tags: youtube, google-account

I have a Google account, from a mail that is not Gmail based.

I would like to have my own Google+ username on YouTube, but I can't do it from within this account, because I just can't find the option.

I don't really know how to do it (as it asked in a popup window, in a Gmail account). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to do that as well and I have a Gmail account. I think they are just rolling it out gradually.

I got it a few days ago, you get the pop-up only when trying to make a comment, or somewhere in the Settings menu (can't find it anymore, the settings seem to change a little when you got your Google Account linked).

I'd advise you to just wait and try to comment now and then until it shows up. But make sure you do have a Google Account with the e-mail address. (Maybe signing up for [Google+](http://plus.google.com) can help, it makes sure you have a full Google Profile linked to your account.)

Comment: I already have a Google+ profile, because i saw in google faq, that it is required to have a custom profile.
Nothing yet. I'll choose as answer when it happens